# How to use indentation with `rstudioapi::insertText`

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudioapi

I have a string that I want to paste with indentation into RStudio using the {rstudioapi}. Here is a simple test string:

```r
test_str <- "for (i in seq_along(x)) {\nout[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])\n}"
cat(test_str)

#> for (i in seq_along(x)) {
#> out[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])
#> }
```

When copying the console output and pasting it manually into an R script in RStudio the output has the correct indentation of one tab equalling two spaces (my default setting):

```r
# this is my desired output (directly in a script, not the console):
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  out[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])
}
```

When using `rstudioapi::insertText` the string is inserted in the script without indentation:

```r
rstudioapi::insertText(test_str)

for (i in seq_along(x)) {
out[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]]) # one tab (equalling two spaces) is missing
}
```

How can I add indentation when using `rstudioapi::insertText` or any other function from the {rstudioapi} package?

Reading the documentation I found how to read the system preference for indentation:

```r
rstudioapi::readRStudioPreference("num_spaces_for_tab")
#> 2
```

However, I can't figure out how to make `insertText` use this information.

**More context:**
I'm looking for a way to add indentation programmatically to string outputs. That means, I don't want to add manually `\t` to lines which should have indentation. I'm in a package and have to deal with user input, which makes it probably pretty tough to calculate the correct amount of indentation which is needed. In the example above line 1 and 3 would need no indentation, while line 2 would need one tab or two spaces.

Ideally, I'd like to use no other package than the {rstudioapi} or base R. Looking at the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/reference/rstudio-documents.html) `insertText` also has a location argument which works with positions or ranges in scripts. I'm not sure whether this can be somehow used to include indentation.

I'm also looking at the {datapasta} package which also uses the {rstudioapi} and [here](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta/blob/69d2a6908ff3402079c4a7d1baaae3ae364cf8fb/R/tribble_paste.R) the `"num_spaces_for_tab"`option is used in the `output_context` (in the script called `oc$nspc`), but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `rstudioapi::executeCommand` to launch `reindent` or `reformatCode` commands:

If you run following commands **together** in editor (for example with `ctrl+A` `Ctrl+Enter`):

```
test_str <- "for (i in seq_along(x)) {\nout[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])\n}"
rstudioapi::insertText(test_str)

# Should be adapted to the range you want to reformat (here : all lines)
ranges <- rstudioapi::document_range(c(1, 0), c(Inf, Inf))
rstudioapi::setSelectionRanges(ranges)
rstudioapi::executeCommand('reformatCode')
```

You get:

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  out[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])
}
```

List of available command IDs is available [here](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/rstudio_ide_commands/rstudio_ide_commands.html).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't hear about an *indentation feature* in `rstudioapi` library.

But I know, that the `styler` has this possibility.

Maybe, it will be also helpful for you.

**An example:**

```
library(styler)

test_str <- "for (i in seq_along(x)) {\nout[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])\n}" #your code

style_text(test_str, indent_by = 3)
```

**An output:**

```
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
   out[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])
}
```

Let's add this into `insertText`

```
> rstudioapi::insertText(style_text(test_str, indent_by = 3))
named list()
> for (i in seq_along(x)) {
+    out[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])
+ }
```

**It works?**

---

**An addition**

Maybe this?

Add `\t` to our string.

```
test_str <- "for (i in seq_along(x)) {\n\tout[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])\n}"
```

Because you want to see **two spaces**, let's do this:

```
> insertText(gsub('\\t','  ', test_str))
named list()
> for (i in seq_along(x)) {
+   out[[i]] <- sum(x[[i]])
+ }
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea! It's working. I upvoted, but ideally I'd prefer an approach only using the `rstudioapi`. The fact, that we can extract the indentation suggests that it is somehow possible to also use this information when pasting text.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Look to an addition ;)

Comment: Thank your very much for your effort! Although adding `\t` would work in theory, I'm in a package and deal with user inputs, so guessing how many tabs are needed in which line is probably pretty difficult, I'd say. I added some more context to my question above.

Comment: @TimTeaFan In the Europe is late already, I'll try to think tomorrow ;)

Comment: @TimTeaFan I haven't any ideas, how to force ```inserttext``` works rightly :( Maybe you should ask at github? https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/